# How to display multiple rest service war files docs on single swagger-ui page?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, swagger, swagger-ui

We have multiple service war files **(i.e.; users.war and visitors.war)** and also **swagger-ui.war** file in the same app server.

Both users.war and visitors.war contains Swagger core specification.

**users.war url:**

```
https://www.dev.example.com/api/users
https://www.dev.example.com/api/user?id=xxx
```

**visitors.war url:**

```
https://www.dev.example.com/api/visitors
```

**swagger-ui.war url:**

```
https://www.dev.example.com/api/api-docs
```

Now my question is when i click the https://www.dev.example.com/api/api-docs url how to display both the users.war and visitors.war services all together at the same place.

Currently when i hit the url https://www.dev.example.com/api/api-docs and enters the users.war url in the textbox it displays the respective users services
and when i enters visitors.war url , it displays the respective visitors services.

Instead of entering the respective service war url each time, i want one swagger-ui url which displays multiple war files services at one place.

Answer (score 0):

what I am suggesting is creating a seperate /api-docs end point, this is NOT generated automatically, but static json file, such as:

```
{
"apiVersion":"1.0",
"swaggerVersion":"1.2",
"apis":[
    {
        "path": "http://localhost:3000/api-docs/projects.json",
        "description":"Projects"
    },
    {
        "path": "http://localhost:3000/api-docs/users.json",
        "description":"Users"
    },
    {   "description":"Retrieve events.",
        "path":"http://localhost:8080/api-docs/default/events",
        "position":0
    },
      { "description":"Retrieve activities.",
        "path":"http://localhost:8080/api-docs/default/activities",
        "position":0
    }
],
```

}

And then you can continue to use all your current swaggger solutions.

Comment: I didn't understand what you were trying to suggest.